# How to alter boolean value returned by mockito implemented interface?

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I use mockito and want a method implemented by default by mockito to return boolean value of true instead of false. I am aware that default method implementation returns default boolean value in Java language which is false.

Is there any mockito-specific method, workaround to solve this problem or i will be forced to provide my own 'mocking' implementation?

```
interface ExampleInterface {
public boolean returnBoolean();
}

ExampleInterface exampleImplementation = mock(ExampleInterface.class);
System.out.println("Resulting value is: " + 
exampleImplementation.returnBoolean());
```

OUTPUT:

```
Resulting value is: false
```

I would like to make it return true instead of false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mockito provides method stubbing with `when(mock.method()).thenReturn(someValue)`. You can use it when you want the mock to return a particular value when a particular method is called.

So here, you can use it as:

```
Mockito.when(exampleImplementation.returnBoolean()).thenReturn(true);
```